# Different predictions on every run with GaussianProcessRegressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gaussian-process

I'm trying to predict and find a maximum of a target function using Gaussian Processes. However, at times, the predictions I get from the GPR are flat and constant throughout the range. If I run it again, it may work fine. I'm attaching here some code to reproduce:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import Matern
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

use_scalar = False

scalerx = StandardScaler()
scalery = StandardScaler()

data_target = np.array([[ 4.11527487e+00, -5.25998354e-02],
                       [ 9.87746489e-02, -4.13503230e-02],
                       [ 3.57381547e+00, -5.25998354e-02],
                       [ 1.60683672e+00, -5.25998354e-02],
                       [ 5.26929603e+00, -6.18080378e-02],
                       [ 9.08232311e-01, -5.25998354e-02],
                       [ 2.39112060e-01, -3.52116406e-02],
                       [ 4.29874823e+00, -4.23911691e-02],
                       [ 9.88334539e-01, -5.25998354e-02],
                       [ 3.10196661e+00, -5.25998354e-02],
                       [ 7.87734943e-01, -5.25998354e-02],
                       [ 8.27486483e-01, -5.16990900e-02],
                       [ 3.80523113e+00, -5.25998354e-02],
                       [ 7.03828442e-01, -2.22452462e-02],
                       [ 5.83227361e+00, -3.09045196e-02],
                       [ 4.65850859e+00, -2.24894464e-02],
                       [ 5.35498380e+00, -4.55683947e-02],
                       [ 5.15052521e+00, -2.59802818e-02],
                       [ 3.43894560e+00, -5.25998354e-02],
                       [ 3.40215825e+00, -5.25998354e-02],
                       [ 0.00000000e+00, -4.35041189e-03],  # <- manually added point
                       [ 6.28318531e+00, -4.35041189e-03]]) # <- manually added point

krnl = Matern(nu=2.5)
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=krnl, alpha=1e-6, normalize_y=True, n_restarts_optimizer=5, random_state=np.random.RandomState())

if(use_scalar):
    # gp.set_params(kernel__length_scale=0.)
    scalerx.fit(data_target[:,0:1])
    scalery.fit(data_target[:,1:])
    X = scalerx.transform(optimizer._space.params)
    Y = scalery.transform(optimizer._space.target)
else:
    X = data_target[:,0:1]
    Y = data_target[:,1:]

gp.fit(X, Y)

# predict
x_pnts = np.linspace(0, 6.28, 1000).reshape(-1,1)
if(use_scalar):
    x = scalerx.transform(x_pnts)
else:
    x = x_pnts

mu, sigma = gp.predict(x, return_std=True)
if(use_scalar):
    mu = scalery.inverse_transform(mu.reshape(-1,1))

plt.scatter(data_target[:,0], data_target[:,1], marker='*')
plt.scatter(x_pnts, mu, marker='.')

plt.show()
```

I tried scaling, I tried setting the length_scale but neither really helped (unless I'm doing it wrong).
How is it possible that I'm getting different predictions for the same data? How do I correct this behavior?
[image: flat prediction example]
[image: good prediction example]

and there's also a different behavior that is mostly flat but predicts just the points that are trained with.

Comment: You should really study what a Gaussian Process is and how predictions are made, its a distribution, a probabilistic model, there is randomness in it (its literally a random variable over functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're explicitly putting in randomness via `random_state=np.random.RandomState()`, and then you're not seeding it anywhere, so of course it's going to be different every run. Try `random_state=np.random.RandomState(1337)`.

---

I've adapted your code a little, using [sklearn's docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gpr_noisy_targets.html#gaussian-processes-regression-basic-introductory-example) for what I think you might actually want to be doing. I got rid of the scaler for simplicity's sake:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import Matern
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor

data_target = np.array([[ 4.11527487e+00, -5.25998354e-02],
                       [ 9.87746489e-02, -4.13503230e-02],
                       [ 3.57381547e+00, -5.25998354e-02],
                       [ 1.60683672e+00, -5.25998354e-02],
                       [ 5.26929603e+00, -6.18080378e-02],
                       [ 9.08232311e-01, -5.25998354e-02],
                       [ 2.39112060e-01, -3.52116406e-02],
                       [ 4.29874823e+00, -4.23911691e-02],
                       [ 9.88334539e-01, -5.25998354e-02],
                       [ 3.10196661e+00, -5.25998354e-02],
                       [ 7.87734943e-01, -5.25998354e-02],
                       [ 8.27486483e-01, -5.16990900e-02],
                       [ 3.80523113e+00, -5.25998354e-02],
                       [ 7.03828442e-01, -2.22452462e-02],
                       [ 5.83227361e+00, -3.09045196e-02],
                       [ 4.65850859e+00, -2.24894464e-02],
                       [ 5.35498380e+00, -4.55683947e-02],
                       [ 5.15052521e+00, -2.59802818e-02],
                       [ 3.43894560e+00, -5.25998354e-02],
                       [ 3.40215825e+00, -5.25998354e-02],
                       [ 0.00000000e+00, -4.35041189e-03],  # <- manually added point
                       [ 6.28318531e+00, -4.35041189e-03], # <- manually added point
                       ])

krnl = Matern(nu=2.5, length_scale_bounds=(1e-3, 1e6))
noise_level = data_target[:,1].std()
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=krnl, alpha=noise_level**2, normalize_y=True, n_restarts_optimizer=25, random_state=np.random.RandomState())

X = data_target[:,0:1]
Y = data_target[:,1:]

gp.fit(X, Y)

# predict
x = np.linspace(0, 6.28, 1000).reshape(-1,1)

mean_prediction, std_prediction = gp.predict(x, return_std=True)
plt.scatter(data_target[:,0], data_target[:,1], marker='*', label="data points")
plt.plot(x, mean_prediction, alpha=0.8, label="mean prediction from GP")
plt.fill_between(x[:,0], mean_prediction - 1.96 * std_prediction, mean_prediction + 1.96 * std_prediction, alpha=0.4, label="95% confidence interval")
# plt.plot(x, gp.sample_y(x, n_samples=3), "--", alpha=0.3, label="sample draws")
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image: mean and std of GP regression]

As you can see, the fit is not that great (my implementation probably leaves something to be desired... not sure what, though). However, the important point I wanted to illustrate here is seen if we turn on the commented-out line at the end, and switch of the confidence interval:

[image: mean and random draws]

Here you can see a few samples of the inherently random predictions you were getting before. Taking their standard deviation (can be done analytically AFAIK, which is neat) gives you the orange confidence interval from the plot before.

Comment: Well yes, but the question is how am I supposed to know a-priori which random state will give me satisfying results? Why do I get flat lines on some predictions and how can I avoid that? (I guess other than detecting that it's flat and trying again with a different random state?)

Comment: You really can't! @Dr. Snoopy's comment above is entirely correct. You can't think of GPs as a "function", more like "a collection of random functions that each sort of fits the data, and you make predictions based on the behavior of a whole population of them". So that randomness is really crucial. [The illustration at this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging#Simple_kriging) is a good illustration of how they actually work. For now, I think you might actually want to choose a different regressor...